# Securing a https connection

Tags: security, spring-security

I have exposed some rest services in spring, using spring mvc, I have secured the webapp using spring security, that uses bcrypt on the server to encode the password and store it in the datbase.

The user will send the password in the url in plain text under https, And i have written a custom basic_auth_filter to check the uername and passowrd - basically authenticate. I also have set up a firewall that only allows one ip to connect.

Im no security expert, is there anything else i need to, should i encode the username/password in the url.. even though it will be coming via https?

regards

ps. this was a requirement to use username on the url?

Comment: Although https will secure the connection, I would suggest the use of a "salted hash" of the password. Instead of sending the password "in the clear" over the link, the client sends a hash of it. The server, likewise, stores a hash. ### There are an **abundance** of source-code libraries that already take care of this issue. Look, on GitHub and elsewhere (and in Google ...), to see what *other people* have already done, and shared.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Incorrect, the salting must be done on the server. The OP is correct in password security. If there is any concern about the https connection the client should pin the certificate.

Comment: Duly acknowledged. Thank you. Perhaps you could "Answer" the question with a more-detailed clarification of what, in your opinion, is the "right" vs. the "wrong" way? I'm sure that the OP, and others, would appreciate it.

Comment: @user1555190 "custom pre_auth_filter to check the uername and passowrd" is worrisome, please elaborate. The password should not be used other than to authenticate using bcrypt.

Comment: For more information on handling passwords See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

and OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

Comment: @MikeRobinson Whatever is sent to the server as the password essentially is the password from the server's view point. What are you trying to accomplish by hashing the uuser's password prior to sending over https? WRT "an abundance of source-code libraries" the issue is picking one that is secure, just because something in on GitHub does not mean it is good or should be used.

Comment: @zaph I update dit the above, it was meant to be a basic _auth_filter which allows me to get the paremeters request.getParameter( username). But would security regarding sending username over url still be a major concern if im limiting only a specified server can connect?

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords, and all other non-ephemeral credentials, should never be sent in the URL, if for no other reason then because the browsers and other HTTP tools and servers will remember this in history, various logs etc, HTTPS or not, making it trivial to steal by anyone with local access, or even by someone just looking over your shoulder. This is why Spring by default rejects authentication via GET requests.

For this reason, you should move the sensitive parameters to the body of the request (thus requiring a POST).

If your login flow is based on username/passwords, I recommend you use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` as it already encapsulates the logic and best practices for this type of flow.

Comment: @kaqqo sorry i mena to say basic auth filter, which extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter which allows me to get the parameters request.getParameter( usernameParameter )

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable enough. But move the params to the body for the reasons above. This is why UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter only allows POST requests.

Comment: @kaqqo Moving it to body makes it more secure? how so? will they be encoded? when being sent over https?..sorry  i know very little about security in webapps... any resoucres would be good..

Comment: I explained above already. They won't be encrypted, apart from the whole request being already encrypted by HTTPS, but the visited URLs (including parameters) can easily be retrieved from browser's history allowing anyone with local access to get the password. Heck, someone could just be looking over your shoulder and see the password in the URL. There's a reason Spring normally prevents logging in via GET requests.

Answer (score 1):

In general your scheme is secure.

Consider pinning the server, that is validating the server certificate, to ensure the connection is to your server.

The password should not be used other than to authenticate using (in your case) bcrypt.

Re question update: "HTTPS encrypts the query string, only the actual server address portion is un-encrypted. But, the full URL including query string will probably be logged by the server so that has security implication. It is best to send confidential information in a POST.